# Is Python function .eq() case sensitive?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I can't seem to find any literature online to help me with my question. I see from the Pandas docs that `.eq()` evaluates comparisons of dataframe objects with constants, series or other dataframe objects (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html).

But my question is will `.eq('ppt')` capture instances of `'PPT'` as well as `'ppt'`?

Comment: No, it won't. You can use `isin(['PPT','ppt'])` or use `.str.lower().eq('ppt')`.

Comment: As the name suggests, it will be calling `__eq__()` on the underlying datatype. Unless you are using a subclass of string for which `__eq__()` is case insensitive, it will default to whatever the `str` behavior is, i.e. case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you Quang Hoang and norok2, your comments have cleared up my confusion. I'll amend my code to be more case insensitive.